# Xcode export archive is missing "export as application"

Tags: xcode, macos

I am trying to export a Mac OS X app using Xcode 4.6 but when I archive and export, I am missing the `export as... application` option as shown [in this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJE9b5vxe_Q)(I don't speak the language, but the video is helpful).

Here is the screen I see:
[image]

What am I missing?  The application runs fine locally. And from the mac docs it doesn't look like I have to sign the app to distribute. Do I have to sign the app to compile to .app file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have configured all linked libraries with "Skip Install" to "YES" in the build settings screen. Also you can click "Validate" to find potential problems
Alternative just save the adhoc build with distrubution certificates is you want to upload it in iTunes and then upload it via application loader provided by apple.

Comment: its my pleasure! enjoy coding

Answer (score 0):

I just checked my version of Xcode to make sure and with Version 4.6.3 (4H1503) of Xcode I see the same screen as in the video with or without code signing turned on. I would make sure you have the most current version of Xcode, clean your build folder and try to Archive again. If that doesn't work I would delete Xcode and reinstall it from the App Store. The other option is to create another user account on your machine and try archiving and distributing from there to see if it is any different (I actually had a problem related to provisioning a few years ago that only showed up on my main user account).